# Usage of Google Advertising Id on Android WITHOUT integrating Google Mobile Ads

Tags: android, google-play-services, ads, google-advertising-id

Getting the Google Advertising ID on Android requires to import the `play-services-ads` dependency.

Starting from 17.0.0, this dependency enforces that the application manifest contain a `<meta-data>` tag with key `com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID`. Missing tag leads to an application crash.

But I want to retrieve the Google Advertising ID for **ads purposes** that are not related to Google mobile Ads, and I do not have an application ID.

Does anyone know how to proceed now ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use *play-services-ads-identifier* instead of *play-services-ads*.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0'
```

This will import only the *Advertising ID* classes, without Google Mobile Ads/AdMob.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I was a bit sceptic about the 16.x version of ads-identifier (as this change was introduced in 17.0.0 of ads) but the 17.x play-services-ads is using exactly the same 16.0.0 version